# Peristent mapped buffer (glBufferStorage GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT) with very small chunks

Tags: c++, opengl

I implemented persistent mapped buffers in a renderer I wrote, very much alike in this tutorial here:
[persistent-mapped-buffers-in-opengl](http://www.bfilipek.com/2015/01/persistent-mapped-buffers-in-opengl.html)

To keep it short, its working like this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
flags = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT;
glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MY_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, flags);
```

Mapping (only once after creation...):

```
flags = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT;
myPointer = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, MY_BUFFER_SIZE, flags);
```

Update:

```
// wait for the buffer   
glClientWaitSync(Buffer.Sync[Index], GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, WaitDuration);

// modify underlying data...
```

lock the buffer:

```
glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
```

After I understood the idea, I was able to implement it without further problems, also gaining quite some performance due to it.
However due to the game engine I am working with, it can't be avoided that I sometimes get a lot of drawcalls with very small chunks, just a few verts. If this happens I get visual distortions, clearly indicating something goes wrong.

What I tried is to add more waits before and after the buffer is updated. Although this wouldn't have made any sense but just for testing, I tried to remove GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT and to use glFlushMappedBufferRange, I tried with a single buffer instead of multiple buffers.

For me it looks like the fence wouldn't work correctly, but I can't see how this could happen.
Shouldn't fencing avoid any trouble like this, even if it would mean sacrificing performance?
The same situation however works without any trouble if I use glBufferData instead, or as said already, if the chunks are a few hundred verts instead and reduced drawcalls.
Any hints what this could be caused by or how I could get more information about what is failing would be very helpful.
There are no OpenGL errors at all.

Comment: We need to see more code. For example, what causes the buffer to become "locked"? That is, when are you sending that fence sync and when are you waiting on it? Are you double-buffering your transfers of vertex data? And so forth.

Comment: I try to provide anything needed :)
It doesn't seem to matter if I use 1 buffer, 3 or more. Regarding this tutorial, the lock is done with deleting a previously sync and using glFenceSync. I am not sure if this is the right term, but that's how it was described in this tutorial. The complete code of this tutorial is here:
https://github.com/fenbf/GLSamples/blob/master/src/PersistentMappedBuffer.cpp I can also add more of my code here, but it should work exactly the same (unless I've overseen something)

Comment: I just added for testing yet a couple more fences and syncs, no matter if it made sense or not. Even adding glFinish() on various places didn't "fix" this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was on an entirely different place and a combination of things.

For multiple buffers it was instead setting an index in

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, VertSize);
```

necessary to set the offset for the multiple buffers in

```
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, StrideSize, (void*) BeginOffset));
```

and the problem for the single buffer distortions came due to a missing wait or rather a wrong "if" when having only one.

I hope that this may be useful for someone else running into such a problem to know that it is no general issue with persistent mapped buffers.